# Client in java 6 for doint http post on tls

Tags: java, security, ssl

I have a consumed a payment gateway to which I was doing http post. Now payment gateway has been changed to tlsv1.2. Can I do http POST from java code, in tls v1.2 ??

I am current on java 1.6, server is tomcat.

Sources say I have to move to 1.7 .. Is it true ??

And can anybody guide me to how to do httpPost via tls v1.2

any refrence regarding same is welcome

Comment: Also, possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237569/httpclient-supporting-multiple-tls-protocols

Comment: please check agaain read the comments .. check the edits.. I have only posted the true or not part .. super user people only told me to miograte

Comment: Spring RESTTemplate is the easiest way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Sources say I have to move to 1.7 .. Is it true ??

Yes, you have to move to 1.7 as JDK6 only supports TLSv1.

[image: Supported TLS protocols by JDK version]

cf. https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/diagnosing_tls_ssl_and_https

Note that TLSv1.1 and TLS1.2 are [by default not enabled for client connections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#tlsprotonote) in 1.7 (they are in 1.8):

> Although SunJSSE in the Java SE 7 release supports TLS 1.1 and TLS
>   1.2, neither version is enabled by default for client connections. Some servers do not implement forward compatibility correctly and
>   refuse to talk to TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2 clients. For interoperability,
>   SunJSSE does not enable TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2 by default for client
>   connections.

Comment: do you have any link to tutorial or reference where tls v 1.2 is implemented

Comment: @ManMohanVyas: Currently not, sorry. But maybe enabling support is your only issue. Do you have any specific problems?

Comment: look there was payment gateway server written in https it was working even if I was just doing http post. from java code. don't know how .. know they have changed it to tls .. I need to accomodate same ..so looking for references and impact