# SSLContext protocols

Tags: java, security, ssl

I am writing a Java TLS *client*. I have several questions regarding how to most securely use the SSLContext class so that TLS is used, when possible, and SSLv3 is only used when TLS is unavailable. (Side note: I see that the documentation says TLS1.1 and TLS1.2 are disabled for clients due to some incompatibility issues with certain vendor products).

1. Does `SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")` *only* use SSL protocols or are
   TLS protocols used if they are available?
2. What are the default protocols when you use `SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")` and what is their order of precedence?
3. Does `SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")` *only* use TLS protocols or are SSL protocols used if they are available?
4. What are the default protocols when you use `SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")` and what is their order of precedence?
5. Is it true, as I assume, that the *default* protocols are always used first and the *supported* protocols are only used if none of the default protocols work for both sides of the handshake?

The Java documentation is unclear on many of these points. For example it says "choosing TLSv1 may make 1.0, 1.1, and 1.2 available".

6. If I use `SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1")` is SSLv3 unavailable or is it just not a default?

When I ask about order of precedence, I'm asking if multiple things are all listed as "defaults" which one will actually be used as the first priority? Also, obligatory yes I've read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504173/sslcontext-initialization).

Answer (score 4):

As [#11504173](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11505994/687476) (after edit) says, all contexts can support all protocols although the **default** may vary.

There is no "order of precedence"; for all protocols implemented by Java (SSLv3 and the three TLSes)
the client states the *maximum* protocol version it supports, and the server selects its own *maximum* or the client's offer whichever is lower,
giving **the highest version supported by both peers**. If the client's offered max is unacceptably low for the server, the server rejects the hello.
If the server's chosen max is unacceptably low for the client, the client aborts the handshake. In particular Java client throws an exception something like "server protocol x is not allowed" and the socket isn't connected.

However some server software didn't implement this negotiation correctly, and wouldn't negotiate the lower-than-max-but-still-acceptable version. To cope with this, if the handshake fails (some?) browsers try again
falsely stating a lower max; that allowed the POODLE attack. Browser developers have learned that web users mostly don't want security, they just want their dancing cat video *now*; Java users seem to be less reckless (so far) and Java does not downgrade except in the way specified by the protocol and to the extent allowed by your configuration.

You may be thinking of *ciphersuites*, where the client does send a list that is nominally ordered by preference,
and the server may choose the "best" shared cipher according to that preference, but it isn't required to.
In fact during the BEAST panic, many servers were configured to give preference to RC4 even if the client didn't list it first.
Then it turned out BEAST wasn't much of a problem while RC4 had much worse weaknesses than previously thought, but some servers
continued to force now-practically-broken RC4 even though clients don't prefer it and https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7465
says you shouldn't use RC4 *at all* much less prefer it. Isn't security fun?