# What is the TLS version in this code snippet of Java 1.7?

Tags: java, ssl, java-security

I am passing JVM parameter as -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2. But in code ,I am explicitly getting the SSL context object as
`SSLContext sc = null; 
sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");`.

Will the TLS version be highest version (1.2) in this case, or i need to explicitly get the TLS version as

```
sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
```

to support TLS version 1.2

Answer (score 1):

Probably not.

[According to the documentation](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/diagnosing_tls_ssl_and_https), this setting is only used by HttpsURLConnection and URl#openStream.

> **https.protocols**
>
> Controls the protocol version used by Java clients which obtain https connections through use of the HttpsURLConnection class or via URL.openStream() operations.

If you directly obtain your own SSLContext, the setting is likely not consulted.

Comment: For Java8, there is a new setting that seems more comprehensive: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504173/sslcontext-initialization `jdk.tls.client.protocols`

Comment: Is there a way to capture the outbound traffic like using wireshark etc and determine the TLS version at runtime?

Comment: ... or a public web service that accepts and dumps HTTPS requests.

Comment: On Wireshark TLS version can be seen asTLSv1 or TLSv1.1...depending on the case. You need to configure protocols in wireshark menu and enter the port on which TLS communication has to be captured.