# what is the protocol be used in SSLContext.getInstance

Tags: java, ssl

I'm tring JDK1.7 with the code below

```
SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
sc.init(null,null,null);
SSLSocketFactory sf = sc.getSocketFactory();
SSLSocket ss = (SSLSocket)sf.createSocket();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ss.getSupportedProtocols()));
```

No matter what protocol I put as `getInstance` parameter, there is no change in the result. I have tried these protocols:

- SSLv2Hello
- SSLv3
- TLSv1
- TLSv1.1
- TLSv1.2

Where does this parameter take effect, as I can call `sslsocket.setEnabledProtocols` to set protocols I want later?

Comment: I had checked some questions, but no answers to this,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504173/sslcontext-initialization
http://serverfault.com/questions/64484/functional-implications-of-differences-in-ssl-and-tls/368574#368574

Comment: Your code worked fine for me when I used `SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");` and the [`SSLContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html) javadoc says *Every implementation of the Java platform is required to support the following standard `SSLContext` protocol: TLSv1*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It affects the *enabled* protocols.

It would be more interesting if you had printed the result of `getEnabledProtocols()` rather than `getSupportedProtocols().`

Comment: yes, you're correct , the result:

SSLContext.getInstance to  ss.getEnabledProtocols

* TLSv1.1  produce  SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1
* SSL  produce  SSLv3, TLSv1
* TLSv1.2  produce  SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2

but it seems that this setting can be overide by ss.setEnabledProtocols, so I guess SSLContext.getInstance is not important?

Comment: It's important if you don't call `setEnabledProtocols().`